# If dontdisplaylastusername is turned on, loginui.exe keeps crashing with Microsoft credential provider V2 sample

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, credential-providers

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
>   "dontdisplaylastusername"=dword:00000001

I was trying to build a custom V2 Credential Provider and basing it off of Microsoft's code sample. The custom credential provider works as expected in most scensrios. However, if I enable the following setting **dontdisplaylastusername**, either through policy or by setting this registry setting and try to go to the login screen, the cursor just spins and the screen just flashes and I am never able to get the login screen to come up. Without any custom v2 credential providers installed, I am able to get to the Other User screen correctly.

How can I fix this? I tried adding a username field to my custom version since Microsoft's version did not have one but that did not change anything and still crashed.

Any ideas?

This is the github repo I was using for the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CredentialProvider)

Here is an example of the fault that is logged for the sample credential provider.

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: LogonUI.exe
P2: 10.0.10586.0
P3: 5632d88c
P4: SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 56cc64dd
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000003086
P9:
P10:
Attached files:
These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_LogonUI.exe_5e45fd9b49f0ea6611374ae56677dfa1cb3a1fe_9798b224_0a4ffaf8
Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 5efbdb96-de9f-4254-b259-1beea7137fc7
Report Status: 96
Faulting application name: LogonUI.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d88c
Faulting module name: SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56cc64dd
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000003086
Faulting process id: 0x3a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1910e42a0efb5
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\LogonUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll
Report Id: 038f9265-0f6f-45fa-bc3e-6c7de490ca34
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```